# IF statement with multiple conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

I can’t get the desired result from a series of conditions in an IF.

```
if (($varteam == $_POST['rteam1']) && ($varteam == $_POST['rteam2']) && ($varteam == $_POST['rteam3'])  && ($varteam == $_POST['rteam4']) && ($varteam == $_POST['rteam5'])) 
{true} 
  else
{false}
```

Starting from the variable $varteam I want to obtain true if all the compared values are identical, otherwise false.

The compared values may also be null.

With the code I’ve posted it works if all the values are equal or different but I get true instead of false if one or more values are different.

Why does it happen?

Comment: what does $varteam equal when you are getting the false positive?

Comment: How can I see what $varteam equals?

Comment: var_dump($varteam); or print_r($varteam);

Comment: It also helps to post the result of `var_dump ($_POST)` so we can see what values give you wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you may get false positives when you have `0` mixed with `null` or `false`. Just to be on the safe side, use `===` instead of `==` so type checking is in effect. That way, `null` !== `false` !== `0`.

```
if (($varteam === $_POST['rteam1']) &&
    ($varteam === $_POST['rteam2']) &&
    ($varteam === $_POST['rteam3']) &&
    ($varteam === $_POST['rteam4']) &&
    ($varteam === $_POST['rteam5'])) 
{
   // true
} 
else
{
   // false
}
```